# How could I cache images using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, google-places-api

I would like to cache images in Laravel. All the solution I could find where for images I am serving myself but the images are coming from a google places api call. From the place details api call.

So what I would like to do if a user requests the images for a certain location that using my webapp, I would like to cache the images that are retrieved as a result.

The google places details api call retrieves the hash for the image and I can construct the url for the image like this:

```
$photos[] = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=' . 
             $photo->photo_reference . 
            '&sensor=false&maxheight=400&maxwidth=400&key=' . 
             $apiKey;
```

The image is then retrieved and shown in the front end.

We are using the Laravel way by doing something like `Cache::get($id.'photos')` but this only caches the url and that isn't very helpful.

We also found the following link https://github.com/Intervention/imagecache but this repo is quite old and we are using Laravel 5.7 so the techniques employed in this repo are no longer applicable.

Any suggestions would be greatly apreciated!

Comment: It's an old repo because it's not the sort of thing that requires regular updates - "the techniques employed in this repo" still largely apply. Give it a shot before you dismiss it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can download the actual image directly from that URL, then you could go this way:

> User requests the image on your URL `yourdomain.com/your-api/image/{reference}`

- try fetching the image from cache (by URL) and return that if it exists
- else, download the image into one of your `storage` folders
- cache the image by URL
- return your local cached copy of the image
- You'll probably also want to create a command that removes old images from that storage folder

---

Could be something like this (untested)

```
/** @return \Illuminate\Http\Response */
function getImage($reference) {
    $imageUrl = buildImageUrl($reference);
    $hash = getHash($imageUrl);
    if($location = Cache::get("image-$hash")) {
        if(file_exists($location)) {
            return response()->file($location);
        }
    }

    $location = cacheImage($imageUrl, $hash);
    return response()->file($location);
}

function cacheImage($imageUrl, $hash) {
    $hash = getHash($imageUrl);
    $location = storage_path("images/$hash");

    // download the image and cache its filename by hash
    $image = downloadImage($imageUrl, $location);
    file_put_contents($location, $image);
    Cache::put("image-$hash", $location);

    return $location;
}

function getHash($string) {
    return sha1($string);
}
```